# Open Text File and count how many times each IP is listed

Tags: powershell-4.0

I've got a text file with ALOT of IP addresses, each different IP could be in the text file many many times, so I'm trying to write (or get help writing) a Powershell script that will do the following:
1 - Open the text file, count the number of times each IP is listed and 
2 - If the total number is greater than 20 then append that IP to another file called Banned.txt

after this script runs, I will manually delete the file (the file is created by another program) after a few days, I would this script again.

Here' my best attempt:

```bsh
$BadIP = Get-Content -Path G:\ips.txt

foreach ($ip in $BadIP) {
    $matches = Select-String -InputObject $BadIP -Pattern $ip -AllMatches
    $a = $matches.Matches.Count
    $ip + " " + $a
}
```

the above code works, but shows the same ip again and again.  The result looks like this:

```
197.3.11.26   1
188.128.119.172   1
64.71.18.150   1
212.92.107.105   51
95.213.162.132   1
212.92.107.105   51
212.92.107.105   51
212.92.123.202   48
64.74.185.234   1
212.92.107.105   51
212.92.107.105   51
212.92.115.227   45
212.92.123.202   48
212.92.107.105   51
212.92.115.227   45
212.92.123.202   48
```

As you can see, 212.92.107.105 is shown many times.

Update: Working code:

```
$BadIP = Get-Content -Path G:\ips.txt
foreach ($ip in $BadIP) {
    $matches = Select-String -InputObject $BadIP -Pattern $ip -AllMatches
    $a = $matches.Matches.Count
    if ($a -gt 10) {
        Add-Content -Path G:\NewBanned.txt -Value $ip -Force 
    }
}

$B = Get-Content -Path G:\NewBanned.txt | sort | Get-Unique
Set-Content -Path G:\C.txt -Value $B -Force
```

```
197.3.11.26
188.128.119.172
64.71.18.150
212.92.107.105
95.213.162.132
212.92.107.105
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
64.74.185.234
212.92.107.105
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
79.175.133.67
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
186.202.182.154
212.92.115.227
23.97.190.194
212.92.123.202
116.247.79.114
212.92.107.125
212.92.107.105
95.154.89.97
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
37.61.220.2
212.92.115.227
216.210.86.226
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
103.196.30.114
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
72.43.207.8
212.92.123.202
52.176.111.87
51.15.147.173
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
51.15.147.173
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
80.241.45.18
51.15.147.173
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
51.15.147.173
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
51.15.147.173
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
121.122.140.41
61.222.127.100
187.216.131.254
138.201.35.26
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
51.15.147.173
162.250.124.186
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
51.15.147.173
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
51.15.147.173
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
198.71.53.228
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
51.15.147.173
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
121.122.140.41
212.92.107.105
51.15.147.173
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
51.15.147.173
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
51.15.147.173
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
138.201.35.26
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
51.15.147.173
124.97.39.218
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
51.15.147.173
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.118.13.124
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
83.37.113.40
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
78.110.10.245
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
38.110.28.23
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.123.202
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.242
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
212.92.123.202
88.250.238.17
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
88.250.238.17
212.92.123.202
212.92.115.227
212.92.107.105
208.98.255.113
124.97.39.218
177.84.35.46
1.174.101.155
```

Comment: You should put a sample of the file that contains the IP addresses, so people can see how it is formated.

Comment: Dale- Good point.. not sure how to attach a file

Comment: This takes time. you can put a reward on this or at least try to write something. People will help to fix your code :)

Comment: Dale-
Yes, I've tried a few different things.  I've updated my post to include my best attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let PowerShell do the heavy lifting for you. The [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet groups identical input objects and automatically counts them:

```bsh
Get-Content 'G:\NewBanned.txt' |
    Group-Object |
    Select-Object Name, Count
```

Output to a text file like this:

```bsh
Get-Content 'G:\NewBanned.txt' |
    Group-Object |
    ForEach-Object { '{0}    {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Count } |
    Set-Content 'G:\C.txt'
```

Output to a CSV file like this:

```bsh
Get-Content 'G:\NewBanned.txt' |
    Group-Object |
    Select-Object @{n='IPAddress';e={$_.Name}}, Count
    Export-Csv 'G:\C.csv' -NoType
```

The calculated property in the latter is just to replace "Name" with "IPAddress" as the column title.

Comment: Ansgar
WOW!  very efficient!  Thank you for cleaning up my messy code.
Thanks again,
Kevin

Comment: How would only write the Name to C.txt if the count was greater than 10?

Comment: Add a filter `Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 10 }`.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks again for your help